# Powershell documentation option and required arguments syntax

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, manpage

first question here.

I have essentially the same question as the last part of this (the answer there didn't answer that part):

https://superuser.com/questions/1129307/how-to-read-powershell-documentation-syntax

In short: how do I know which arguments are required vs. optional?

For example, the Copy-Item command:

```
SYNTAX
    Copy-Item [-Path] <String[]> [[-Destination] <String>] [-Container] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-Exclude <String[]>] [-Filter <String>] [-Force] [-Include 
    <String[]>] [-PassThru] [-Recurse] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [-UseTransaction [<SwitchParameter>]] [<CommonParameters>]

    Copy-Item [[-Destination] <String>] [-Container] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-Exclude <String[]>] [-Filter <String>] [-Force] [-Include <String[]>] [-PassThru] 
    [-Recurse] -LiteralPath <String[]> [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [-UseTransaction [<SwitchParameter>]] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Is Destination a required parameter? How would I know that?

Lastly, in general, what is the type of question I am asking called? I tried googling "powershell man pages syntax" and "how to read man pages" (for Unix). Really, I am looking for documentation regarding how they wrote the documentation!

Edit: I found this resource for Unix; something similar for Powershell would be great:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required arguments do not have the square brackets.  If the parameter name does not have square brackets, that needs to be declared with the item as it's not bound by position.

This is the closest thing I could find regarding help:
[about_Comment_Based_Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-5.1)

Additionally, if you use the `-online` flag with `Get-Help`, it has very detailed information regarding syntax, parameters, etc.  Often with examples.

Comment: What do you mean "bound by position"? Also, is there a source you could link to? EDIT: just saw the source

Comment: @element_j PowerShell parameters can be bound by position (and often are by default unless specified otherwise) and the different syntaxes you see are defined by something called `ParameterSetName` parameter attributes.

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks. And I think I understand a little more now, `Copy-Item [[-Destination] <String>]` means if the Destination flag is specified, then we MUST include a string. While something like `[-UseTransaction [<SwitchParameter>]]` means that even if `UseTransaction ` is specified, then `SwitchParameter` is optional, right?

Comment: @element_j A `<SwitchParameter>` just means a true/false value.  It's a boolean.  Switches are false by default, and declaring the variable flips it to true.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this video which was rather helpful!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrmDhOJJv-Y